# Inconsistencies in Big-O Analysis of a Basic "Algorithm"

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analytics

I recently learned about formal Big-O analysis of algorithms; however, I don't see why these 2 algorithms, which do virtually the same thing, would have drastically different running times. The algorithms both print numbers 0 up to n. I will write them in pseudocode:

```
Algorithm 1:

def countUp(int n){

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){

        print(n);

    }

}

Algorithm 2:

def countUp2(int n){

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){

            ... (continued so that this can print out all values 0 - Integer.MAX_VALUE)

            for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++){

                print("" + i + j + ... + k);

                if(("" + i + j + k).stringToInt() == n){

                    quit();

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

So, the first algorithm runs in `O(n)` time, whereas the second algorithm (depending on the programming language) runs in something close to `O(n^10)`. Is there anything with the code that causes this to happen, or is it simply the absurdity of my example that "breaks" the math?

Comment: The second function might be slower than the first, but it should still run in _O(n)_ time. How did you get to _O(n^10)_?

Comment: @AtnNn How is the second one O(n)? All loops are bounded by 10

Comment: If you put the number 11 into your second algorithm, you will get the output, "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11"  This is not the same as the first.

Comment: @DebosmitRay The loops are also bounded by the condition `("" + i + j + k).stringToInt() == n`.

Comment: @AtnNn Please correct me if I am wrong. But that should not affect the worst case runtime, right? What if `n` is one more that the max value that you can reach with the loops? For `m` loops, loops are maxed out at `10^m` which is a constant.

Comment: @DebosmitRay You could also say that  `countUp` is _O(1)_. Any function with a runtime of _O(f(n))_ is _O(1)_ if _n_ is bounded. But that isn't very useful.

Comment: @AtnNn Nice point. I made a little edit to my answer based on this discussion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When analyzing the runtime of an algorithm, one key thing to look for is the loops. In algorithm 1, you have code that executes n times, making the runtime O(n). In algorithm 2, you have nested loops that each run 10 times, so you have a runtime of O(10^3). This is because your code runs the innermost loop 10 times for each run of the middle loop, which in turn runs 10 times for each run of the outermost loop. So the code runs 10x10x10 times. (This is purely an upper bound however, because your if-statement may end the algorithm before the looping is complete, depending on the value of n).

Comment: what do you mean? where is `n` used as a loop bound? loop bounds are independent of n

Comment: @DebosmitRay I just used n for consistency with the first example in order to explain how looping affects the analysis. I suppose I should have used another letter since n is used for a separate purpose in this case.

Comment: loop bounds are constants. so using `n` invites unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @DebosmitRay Good point. Hopefully it's more clear with the edits.

Comment: Yes sir, I think it is. :)

Answer (score 2):

In `countUp`, the loop hits all numbers in the range [0,n] **once**, thus resulting in a runtime of O(n).

In `countUp2`, you do somewhat the exact same thing, a bunch of times. The bounds on all your loops is 10.

Say you have 3 loop running with a bound of 10. So, outer loop does `10`, inner does `10x10`, innermost does `10x10x10`. So, worst case your innermost loop will run 1000 times, which is essentially constant time. So, for `n` loops with bounds [0, 10), your runtime is 10^n which, again, can be called constant time, O(1), since it is not dependent on `n` for worst case analysis.

Assuming you can write enough loops and that the size of `n` is not a factor, then you would need a loop for every single digit of n. Number of digits in `n` is `int(math.floor(math.log10(n))) + 1`; lets call this `dig`. So, a more strict upper bound on the number of iterations would be 10^dig (which can be kinda reduced to O(n); proof is left to the reader as an exercise).

Comment: Okay. I see. Since the for loops are bounded by a constant then it means it simply runs in O(n) time

Comment: @dsiegler19 No sir. Big-O analysis says that the second function runs in O(1) in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

To count up to `n` in `countUp2`, then you need the same number of loops as the number of digits in `n`: so `log(n)` loops. Each loop can run `10` times, so the total number of iterations is `10^log(n)` which is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first runs in O(n log n) time, since `print(n)` outputs O(log n) digits.

The second program assumes an upper limit for n, so is trivially O(1). When we do complexity analysis, we assume a more abstract version of the programming language where (usually) integers are unbounded but arithmetic operations still perform in O(1). In your example you're mixing up the actual programming language (which has bounded integers) with this more abstract model (which doesn't). If you rewrite the program[*] so that is has a dynamically adjustable number of loops depending on n (so if your number n has k digits, then there's k+1 nested loops), then it does one iteration of the innermost code for each number from 0 up to the next power of 10 after n. The inner loop does O(log n) work[**] as it constructs the string, so overall this program too is O(n log n).

[*] you can't use for loops and variables to do this; you'd have to use recursion or something similar, and an array instead of the variables i, j, k, ..., z.

[**] that's assuming your programming language optimizes the addition of k length-1 strings so that it runs in O(k) time. The obvious string concatenation implementation would be O(k^2) time, meaning your second program would run in O(n(log n)^2) time.